# Canvas element with 'width: 0' in OpenLayers 6 instance on Vue.js

Tags: export, image, openlayers

I am using Vue components to generate multiple instances of OpenLayers in the same parent component.

Ultimately I am attempting to export an image of each instance of OpenLayers using the [html-to-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image) library.

Nearly all of the instances work as expected, with the exception of a specific instance, and sporadically another instance will also not work as expected. The error I receive in my browser console when I attempt to export as PNG, is as follows (seems unhelpful, but maybe I'm missing something):

```
Event {
    bubbles: false
    cancelBubble: false
    cancelable: false
    composed: false
    currentTarget: null
    defaultPrevented: false
    eventPhase: 0
    isTrusted: true
    path: [img]
    returnValue: true
    srcElement: null
    target: null
    timeStamp: 13926.305000000866
    type: "error"
    proto__: Event
}
```

I have identified that the problem within the instances that will not export, is the html generated by OpenLayers has an additional `<div></div>` element, with a `<canvas></canvas>` child element. When I manually delete this element in my browser, the OpenLayers instance will then be successfully exported.

Here is an example of an OpenLayers instance that works:

```
<div class="ol-viewport" touch-action="none" data-view="61" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; touch-action: none;">
    <div class="ol-unselectable ol-layers" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">
        <div class="ol-layer" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <canvas width="377" height="377" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; transform-origin: left top; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ol-overlaycontainer" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is an example that *doesn't* work

```
<div class="ol-viewport" touch-action="none" data-view="119" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; touch-action: none;">
    <div class="ol-unselectable ol-layers" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">
        <div class="ol-layer" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <canvas width="0" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; transform-origin: left top;">
            </canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="ol-layer" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <canvas width="377" height="377" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; transform-origin: left top; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ol-overlaycontainer" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div><div class="ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

The most notable part of the broken OpenLayers instance, is the width of the new `<div></div>` is 0. If I make this anything other than 0, the export will then work as expected.

Here is the code snippet that should export the map to PNG:

```
public getImage() {
  var exportOptions = { 
    filter: function(element) {
      return element.className ? element.className.indexOf('ol-control') === -1 : true;
    }   
  };  

  htmlToImage.toPng(this.map.getTargetElement(), exportOptions)
    .then((dataUrl: string) => {
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = dataUrl;
      this.emitImage(img);
    })  
    .catch((e: any) => {
      console.log(e);
    }); 
}
```

I'm unsure of exactly why OpenLayers is adding this particular `<div></div>` and only on this one instance (and more interestingly why intermittently on one other), the maps themselves render perfectly, as expected.

One workaround I have considered looking into would be to change my method of exporting to PNG using the html-to-image library, to somehow filter out this unwanted element, but I would much rather get the bottom of why OpenLayers behaves like this in the first place.

Comment: It may be a vector layer with no features visible.  The problem can also occurs in https://openlayers.org/en/v6.1.1/examples/export-pdf.html if you zoom in to somewhere where the vector feature is not visible.  That example has been updated for the next release.

Comment: @Mike Yes, I can confirm this seems to occur consistently when no features are visible. Do you think this could this be considered a bug?

Comment: It is reasonable enough for OpenLayers to reduce a canvas to zero if it not needed, and a deficiency in html-to-image to not handle it correctly.